# How do I run an Apps Script function from an HTML dialog box?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

Edited: It all works now, I just tried running it using Edge instead of Chrome and it worked for whatever reason. Thanks to everyone who responded!

I am trying to make a script using Google Apps Script that writes to the next line of a Google Sheet using a button in a custom dialog box. I decided to take this approach because I need to manually process a large amount of data, and creating a dialog box with some checkboxes in a Google Sheet is the way my team decided to go.

My issue seems to be that using google.script.run.writeToSheet() is not working correctly. The My Executions tab shows that writeToSheet fails every time it is called, but when I call writeToSheet in the onOpen function it works as intended. Am I using google.script.run incorrectly or something?

Here is my Apps Script code:

```
function onOpen() {
  writeToSheet();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.addMenu("Detection", [{name: "Detection", functionName: "showDialog"}])
}

function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
      .setWidth(500)
      .setHeight(450);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Marine Mammal Detection");
}

function writeToSheet() {
  var curSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = curSheet.getLastRow();
  var cellRange = "D"+String(lastRow+1)+":G"+String(lastRow+1);
  curSheet.getRange(cellRange).setValues([['g', 'g', 'g', 'g']]);
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="addDetection()"/>
    <script>
      function onFailure(error) {
        google.script.host.close();
      }

      function onSuccess(error) {
        //google.script.host.close();
      }

      function addDetection() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).withFailureHandler(onFailure).writeToSheet();
        //google.script.host.close();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk There is no error message, it just says "failed" in the status column.

Comment: There should be a message in the execution log

Comment: I've tried running it a few times, but I don't get any error messages. I checked the cloud log too, and nothing.

Comment: I don't get it, what's the status column then? Can you share a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="addDetection();"/>
    <script>
      function addDetection() {
        google.script.run.writeToSheet();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

GS:

```
function writeToSheet() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1 , 1, 1, 4).setValues([[1,2,3,4]]);
}
```

Try this and suppy comma separated values:

```
function writeToSheet(v) {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1 , 1, 1, v.length).setValues([v]);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="addDetection();"/>
    <script>
      function addDetection() {
        let v = document.getElementById('txt1').value.split(',');
        google.script.run.writeToSheet(v);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just tried this, but it still said that it failed. The same thing is happening where your writeToSheet function works when run in onOpen, but it doesn't work when I click the button in the dialog box.

Comment: It's still not working for me, so maybe I'm doing something else wrong. Did you have to deploy it as a Web App?

Comment: No I'm running it as a dialog

Comment: And it worked when you clicked the submit button in the dialog box under the detection menu? For me, it still says that it failed. I'm thinking the issue must not be with how I'm calling the function, but I have no idea what else it could be. The comma-separated version did not work either.